# Toggle CSS on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a console setup on a tool I've created. The console can be minimized when clicked and maximized when clicked again.

The issue however is that once I maximize it, it simply minimizes when it is complete. What are my options?

```
$('#consolebutton').mouseup(function() {
        if ($('#footconsole').height(200)) {
            $('#footconsole').animate({
                height: 14
            }, 100)
        } else if ($('#footconsole').height(14)) {
                $('#footconsole').animate({
                height: 200
            }, 100);
        }
});
```

(I do realize that checking the height of the div, is actually setting the height of the div and that is the problem.)

http://jsfiddle.net/VaDBW/3/

Comment: Why don't you use `.click` instead of `.mouseup`?

Comment: the method doesn't matter to me, just the outcome. both have the same outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
$('#consolebutton').mouseup(function() {
    var $footconsole = $('#footconsole');
    if ($footconsole.height() == 200) {
        $footconsole.animate({
            height: 14
        }, 100)
    } else {
        $footconsole.animate({
            height: 200
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

It does a comparison against height (rather than set it), and I also set a variable to the value of `$("#footconsole")`, rather than keep searching for it.

Comment: Here's a fiddle using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/WHpee/ . Click on the green 'button'

Answer (score 1):

Call the `height()` method without parameters.  Without parameters, it returns the current height.  When passing a parameter, it is setting the height.

`if($('#footconsole').height() == 14)` for example.  Though in my opinion you're better off saving a status flag in `data` versus checking height

```
if($('#footconsole').data('collapsed'))
{
    $('#footconsole').data('collapsed', false);
    /* do expand code */
} else {
     $('#footconsole').data('collapsed', true);
     /* do collapse code */
}
```

You can also use a class to define the settings and, if you need to do more than just toggle the class, you can check with `hasClass` to make further adjustments.  Lots of options.  But going off of raw height seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

I would use toggleClass() inside of a click(function(){...}); and then you dont need the if statements and you can put the height differences in the CSS.